# Creating the right key for my JSON objects

Tags: php, json

I'm creating JSON in PHP to read from another app and I want to categorise the JSON data as

```
jobs:
  job:
    ID: 123
    name: Job Name 1
  job:
    ID: 321
    name: Job Name 2
  job:
    ID: 231
    name: Job Name 3
```

What I'm getting instead is

```
0:
  ID: 123
  name: Job Name 1
1:
  ID: 321
  name: Job Name 2
2:
  ID: 231
  name: Job Name 3
```

The PHP code I'm using to create the JSON is as follows:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, name FROM job");
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

What do I need to do to have each item in the JSON categorised as a 'job' and the whole list categorised as 'jobs'?

Comment: You can't (for the first part of your question). How would you distinguish between the different jobs? You can put the whole array in another array with a key of `jobs` if you have to. Not much added value though.

Comment: If I look at Reddit's JSON [link](http://www.reddit.com/.json) it is formatted as children = { and then within that multiple data = {. This is the format I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rs = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, name FROM job");
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr['job'][] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: This gives me the error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: anyway, i think you cant do this because your **KEY** is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try like this

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr['jobs'][]['job'] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Update :**

```
$obj_user1 = new stdClass;
$obj_user1->id = "1";
$obj_user1->name = "a";

$obj_user2 = new stdClass;
$obj_user2->id = "2";
$obj_user2->name = "b";

$obj_user = array($obj_user1,$obj_user2);

foreach($obj_user as $a){
   $arr['jobs'][]['job'] = $a;
}

print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

**Output :**
    `{"jobs":[{"job":{"id":"1","name":"a"}},{"job":{"id":"2","name":"b"}}]}`